# Django query order depending on starts_with and contains

Tags: django, django-models

I try to make a special `contains` filter in django such that,

- if items are cba, abc, abd etc.. and
- if I want to get the items that contains `ab`,

the list should be ordered as `abc,bca` because `abc` starts with `ab` even though they both contains `ab`.

How can I make such query in django effectively ?

My query is at below

```
EmployerIndexed.objects.filter(name__icontains=empkw)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you want an alphabetical sort?

```
EmployerIndexed.objects.filter(name__icontains=empkw).order_by('name')
```